# SOAPUI - How can I Pass Multiple Responses from one request into another request one at a time

Tags: soapui

I am relatively new to SOAPUI and automated testing:

I am basically trying to take the results from one SOAPUI response and parse them to another, which alone is simple enough, but I have multiple responses in the first request and need to Parse and run them one by one into the second.

**Response From Request One:**

```
 <s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"      xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
   <s:Header>
      <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">http://tempuri.org/IWebServices/GetListOfChangedCommunicationsResponse</a:Action>
   </s:Header>
   <s:Body>
      <GetListOfChangedCommunicationsResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
         <GetListOfChangedCommunicationsResult xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <b:long>8888633</b:long>
            <b:long>8888635</b:long>
            <b:long>8888637</b:long>
            <b:long>8888641</b:long>
         </GetListOfChangedCommunicationsResult>
         <CommunicationsIssue xmlns:b="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/International.CD.Entity" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <b:DigiCommErrors i:nil="true"/>
            <b:Errors/>
            <b:Warnings i:nil="true"/>
         </CommunicationsIssue>
      </GetListOfChangedCommunicationsResponse>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>



I need to take those 4 responses <b:long> and pass them into this 2nd method 1 at a time replacing <tem:ReferenceNumber> each time as this method only allows individual requests
```

**Request Two:**

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">
   <soap:Header/>
   <soap:Body>
      <tem:GetCommunicationItem>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <tem:ReferenceNumber>${#TestCase#REF_ID}</tem:ReferenceNumber>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <!--tem:BarCode>?</tem:BarCode-->
      </tem:GetCommunicationItem>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

What would be the best process to accomplish this within SOAPUI?

Comment: Do you need to include all 4 items in the below request with 4 ReferenceNumber elements?

Comment: The 4 <b:long> responses in the first method are to be used as the input for the <tem:ReferenceNumber> in the 2nd method. The 2nd method only allows single entries though, so I need to run/loop the 2nd method 4 times using each of the different responses. It is not always going to be 4 iterations though, the 1st response could have more or less  results

Comment: In single request call (not 4 times), right?

Comment: Sorry I updated my initial response!

Comment: Can't see any updates to the question.

Comment: Ummm, sorry abut that, but in answer to your question - the 2nd request needs to run 4 times(or how ever many responses there are) with a different input from the 1st response each time

Comment: Ok, got you. Need to replease `ReferenceNumber` each time, I guess.

Comment: Yes, this is correct

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. Can tell the sequence of test step in the test case? Just two steps?

Comment: PhilH, would you please try the below solution to see if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to get it working by splitting up the line into separate parts in trying to debug where it was going wrong:

```
def ids = new XmlSlurper().parseText(context.response).​'**'.findAll{it.name() == 'long'}*.text
```

Below is the script I am currently using which was based on @Rau answer. Not usre if my changes are necessarily the best way to do it, but it's working for me

```
def nextStep = 'CommItem'
assert context.response, 'Response is null or empty'
def content = context.expand('${ChangedComms#Response}')
def xml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(content)
def ids =xml.depthFirst().findAll{it.name() == 'long'}*.text()
ids.each {
    log.info ids
    }
assert ids, 'Did not get any values from this response'

def stepToRun = context.testCase.testSteps[nextStep]
ids.each { id ->
    log.info "Running $nextStep step for value $id"
    context.testCase.setPropertyValue('REF_ID', id.toString())
    def runner = stepToRun.run(context.testRunner, context)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the SoapUI test case has two steps.

Say:

- **Step1** : this response has multiple values,  for each value run *Step2*
- **Step2** : request needs a value from previous response

Here is the approach:

- Disable the **Step2**
- Change `<tem:ReferenceNumber>204237800</tem:ReferenceNumber>` to `<tem:ReferenceNumber>${#TestCase#REF_ID}</tem:ReferenceNumber>`. So, that whenever step2 is run, it takes value from test case level custom property and this value is stored by user in Script Assertion before executing Step2.
- Add `Script Assertion` to the **Step1**.
- The script needs to read the response, parse it, extract the values `long` element.
- For each `long` element value, set it at test case level custom Property, say `REF_ID` and execute **Step2** from this script itself.
- By the time `Script Assertion` completes, **Step2** got execute those many times of **Step1**'s response values. Hence, no need to execute the **Step2** again, hence, requested to disable in the beginning.

Here is the Script Assertion for Step1:

```groovy
//Provide / change the name of the test step of Step2
def nextStep = 'Step2'

assert context.response, 'Response is null or empty'
def ids = new XmlSlurper().parseText(context.response).​'**'.findAll{it.name() == 'long'}*.text()
log.info ids

assert ids, 'Did not get any values from this response'

def stepToRun = context.testCase.testSteps[nextStep]
ids.each { id ->
   log.info "Running $nextStep step for value $id"
   context.testCase.setPropertyValue('REF_ID', id.toString())
   def runner = stepToRun.run(context.testRunner, context)
}
```

Comment: Trying to test the script assertion I get the following error  -                        startup failed: Script31.groovy: 15: expecting anything but ''\n''; got it anyway @ line 15, column 62. ... : ${runner.hasResponse()" ^

Comment: @PhilH, thank you for trying and let me know the error, just fixed it in the above answer.

Comment: thank you, and yes that resolved the initial issue, but now I get  the following...............No signature of method: java.lang.String.name() is applicable for argument types: () values: [] Possible solutions: take(int), any(), any(groovy.lang.Closure), wait(), next(), dump().............I understand the issue is with...... it.name()..... I tried a couple of the suggested solutions but I don't believe I actioned correctly as I was getting very similar results

Comment: Is there any change in the response of step1 ? i.e., not the same as it appears in the question?

Comment: Dependent on what you mean - There is a difference in quantity of <b:long> responses e.g. <b:long>8888633</b:long>
            <b:long>8888635</b:long>
         
but also I had stripped out some of the header and other information, only showing the section I wanted to find the results from - do you need the Full Response?

Comment: If you can adopt the solution to your original response, fine. If you need help, then provide, up to you.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help so far, full XML has been provided for both the response from the first method, and the request the outputs need to be passed to as no I do not know how to adapt the script

Comment: Good morning @Rao, I was just following up to see if you were able to provide the resolution?

Comment: @PhilH, the above provided code should still work for the updated xml, as it is still going to read `long` element values only. In the second statement `log.info id` -> does show any data?

Comment: no the error below is coming up, and the Log Output remains empty    **groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.lang.String.name() is applicable for argument types: () values: [] Possible solutions: take(int), any(), any(groovy.lang.Closure), wait(), next(), size() error at line: 5**

Comment: would you mind showing the details - possibly with screen shot? share it via tinyupload.com or someother wya?

Comment: Link to [DropBox}(db.tt/3F1oMFVvKe) . I have uploaded 2 files, one showing screenshots of the Test Runner and also running the scripts manually, and then a second file with the logged outcome in notepad. Let me know if there was a specific screenshot you needed that's not included

Comment: Thank you for the details, will check and get back to you, @PhilH.

Comment: @PhilH, in the below you can find `error log`, would you please add too? By the way, you script is not the updated answer. Please try the above script.

Comment: I have uploaded the file Error_log.txt to the same shared location, after having updated the change in Script you posted.

Comment: @PhilH, as mentioned earlier, have you tried the updated script in answer? If you compare it with your screen shot, it defers. That is the main reason for the error.

Comment: that error log was from after I had deleted the old script and copied in your new one

Comment: @PhilH, I understand that it is frustrating and delayed. But, the above code works. Please see if you are really missing anything carefully in your script or copy paste issues comparing the answer.

Comment: I have added a docx document showing a slight change to you solution which i have made work to the dropbox , all i did was separate out your working solution so not entirely sure what the error message was referring to